# Set bitmask to CRM AccessRights

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, bitmask, access-rights

I have an issue with setting the accessrights for a principal in CRM. I have to retrieve the actual access rights for a particular team set these rights.

Actually  the accessrights are set like this:

```
principal.AccessMask = Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.AccessRights.ReadAccess |                                        Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.AccessRights.AppendAccess |
Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.AccessRights.AppendToAccess |
Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.AccessRights.WriteAccess;
```

Now I have retrieved the relevant accessrights which is returned as object:

```
object AccessRights  = FetchEngine.GetPrincipalPriviliges(Globals.incomingTeamId, Globals.incomingRecordId);
```

This object contains the rights like this: 851991

My issue now is that I don't know exactly how to set the AccessRights for the principal by using this object (bitmask).

Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction.

Any help is very appreciated.

Kind regards
Sandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to: 
[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.accessrights.aspx)
It's an enum with Flags Attribute.  You should be able to just cast it:

```
object rightsObject  = FetchEngine.GetPrincipalPriviliges(Globals.incomingTeamId, Globals.incomingRecordId);
var rights = (Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.AccessRights)rightsObject;
//....
myPrincipal.AccessMask = rights;
```

then do whatever you want with it....